# I have been having this error pop up and i have no idea hot to fix it it says" SeverScriptService.cFolder:32: attempt to index nil with "GetChildren"n

Tags: roblox-studio

this is the line thats wrong ive search on google and it hasent worked im new to coding so if anyone could help me i would be greatfull.

local function getAnimation(char)
local combo = char:GetAttribute("Combo")

```
local anims = combatAnims:GetChildren()

local currAnims = anims[combo]

return currAnims
```

end